# Reference request for research on images or colors used in quizzes and exams

Tags: teaching, exams, reference-request, education

For my exams and quizzes, I print them on colored paper, and I usually try to make them aesthetically appealing with the design. I include pictures that are usually relevant to the material they are being tested on.  I sometimes include funny cartoons.

I do this because I think it makes taking quizzes and exams an experience that is a little more relaxing and fun than if I just had plain white paper with no images.  I also enjoy seeing my students chuckle at a funny picture or cartoon.  I teach undergraduate mathematics, and given that many students have math anxiety, I like to try to take the edge off of that.

Has there been any research done on whether or not having colored paper or images on exams and quizzes are beneficial or detrimental?

Comment: Beware of color blind students.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Do you know of any research that suggests colored paper or colored images on exams are detrimental to color blind students?  I am interested in the use of images or cartoons that are not used as part of a problem, i.e. having a colored graph for example, I would not do that on an exam.  Just illustrations that are not necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: It seems  that print on yellow, pastel or cream-coloured paper is easier to read for dyslexic students: http://www.altformat.org/index.asp?pid=344. From BDA (British Dyslexia Association) [*Many dyslexic people are sensitive to the glare of white backgrounds on a page, white board or computer screen. This can make the reading of text much harder.*](http://www.bdadyslexia.org.uk/dyslexic/eyes-and-dyslexia)

Comment: @FelixY. I don't have any reference, but I know a few people who, being color blind, have difficulties in reading information from colored displays (e.g. instrument displays) or images.

Answer (score 4):

With a quick Google search, I found the following, but I am interested if there is anything more than these, especially with mathematics or studies with images:

"Effect of Paper Color on Students' Physics Exam Performances" by David R. Schmidt, Todd G. Ruskell, and Patrick B. Kohl

https://www.academia.edu/5702205/Effect_of_Paper_Color_on_Students_Physics_Exam_Performances

"The Non-Impact of Paper Color on Exam Performance" by Michael J. Meyer and Jennifer Bagwell:
http://aaajournals.org/doi/abs/10.2308/iace-50142

"Effect of Paper Color and Question Orderon Exam Performance" by Ilanit R. Tal, Katherine G. Akers, and Gordon K. Hodge

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233180281_Effect_of_Paper_Color_and_Question_Order_on_Exam_Performance